# Unable to record using AudioRecord in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am developing an Android app. In my app I need to record audio using AudioRecord class. Now I am creating a simple app to test AudioRecord class because I have never used that before. My simple app is when user click "Record" button start keep recording. When click "stop", stop recording. Then "play" button to play recorded audio. But my app giving me error when I click "Record" button.

This is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Boolean recording;


    private Button btnPlay,btnStop,btnRecord;
    private String outputFile = null;
    //outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        initViews();
        setUpViews();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {

    }

    private void initViews()
    {
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    }

    private void setUpViews()
    {
        btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRecord();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recording = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            while(recording){
                int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                    dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                }
            }

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void playRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Error throws when I click record button.

This is the error in Logcat:

[image]

What is the error? How can I use AudioRecord correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem. I just needed to run new thread for recording.

```
 private void startRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            final int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            final AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while(recording){
                        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                            try{
                                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```